# java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I need to read a file stored in my project's resources, the directory is `src/main/resources/dataset/dataset.dat`.
I'm using the following lines of Scala code to read a text file from HDFS and parse as Spark RDD of dataset objects:

```scala
// init Spark context
val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("mydataset").setMaster("local")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

// read dat file
val resource = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("dataset/dataset.dat")
val dsRdd: RDD[DatasetObject] = sc.textFile(resource.toString(), 1).map(line => DatasetData.parse(line))
```

but the following error occurred:

```
class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/grader/grader.jar!/dataset/dataset.dat
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/grader/grader.jar!/dataset/dataset.dat
```

I tried to read the file in another way but the error keeps occurring:

```
val dsRdd: RDD[DatasetObject] = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/dataset/dataset.dat").map(line => DatasetData.parse(line))
```

**Important:** Unit tests are successfully run locally, the problem occurs on the remote test environment.

Comment: Can you describe your remote test environment? Cloud? Remember that the workers try to load the file, is it available to them?

Comment: @jgp sorry but I haven't details about the remote environment because it is the Coursera online lab used for the assignments.

Comment: I think your issue is with the path nevertheless…  is it an old course? RDDs are so 2018 :)

Comment: `src/main` does not exist in your JAR or after the code compiles. There is a class called `SparkFiles`, I believe, which you should be using here.

Comment: @jgp maybe yes :) this is the course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your time, I found a solution. I leave a comment below :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was using `getResource` and `textFile`, I had to use a combination of `getResourceAsStream` and `sc.parallelize` as follow:

```scala
def lines: List[String] = {
    Option(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/dataset/dataset.dat")) match {
      case None => sys.error("Please download the dataset as explained in the assignment instructions")
      case Some(resource) => Source.fromInputStream(resource).getLines().toList
    }
  }
```

and parse as Spark RDD of dataset objects

```scala
val dsRdd: RDD[DatasetObject] = sc.parallelize(lines).map(line => DatasetData.parse(line))
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, it's preferred to send it with `spark-submit ...  --files` rather than as part of the JAR